# handle over exception in JMS operations

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

I am using activeMQ 5.4 for JMS implementation in my project.
I want to notify user every time application fails to send a message 
but I am not getting any handle at occurrence of an exception.
For instance, In case JMS broker is down and I perform a create connection, session etc. or a message send operation within a try block, 
control never comes back to catch block or ExceptionListener set for the connection.
My code looks like:

```
connection = (TopicConnection) (new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(localBrokerURL)).createConnection();
connection.setExceptionListener(new ExceptionListener() {               
    @Override
    public void onException(JMSException arg0) {
        System.out.println("Exception Occurred");
    }
});
connection.start();
final TopicSession session =conn.createTopicSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
final Topic sendTopic = session.createTopic("someTopicName");
```

where Value of localBrokerURL is

```
failover://(ssl://localhost:61618?trace=true&wireFormat.maxInactivityDuration=0)
```

Please help. Any hint is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that is the intent of the failover: transport. It will hide transport failures and automatically try and reconnect, replaying any jms state when a new connection is established.
There is a transportListener that you can use to get transport suspended and resumed events.
If you remove the failover: component from the broker url, you will get all exceptions propagated up to your client.

Answer (score 0):

just set the `timeout` property on the connection URI and it will throw an error instead of block the thread...

```
failover://(ssl://localhost:61618?trace=true&wireFormat.maxInactivityDuration=0)?timeout=10000
```

see http://activemq.apache.org/failover-transport-reference.html